# Is it possible to use beautiful soup to extract multiple types of items?

Tags: beautifulsoup

I've been looking at documentation and they don't cover this issue. I'm trying to extract all text and all links, but not separately. I want them interleaved to preserve context. I want to end up with an interleaved list of text and links. Is this even possible with BeautifulSoup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is definitely possible.

```
import urllib2
import BeautifulSoup

request = urllib2.Request("http://www.example.com")
response = urllib2.urlopen(request)
soup = BeautifulSoup.BeautifulSoup(response)
for a in soup.findAll('a'):
    print a
```

Breaking this code snippet down, you are making a `request` for a website (in this case Google.com) and parsing the `response` back with BeautifulSoup. Your requirements were to find all links and text and keep the context. The output of the above code will look like this:

```
<a href="/"><img src="/_img/iana-logo-pageheader.png" alt="Homepage" /></a>
<a href="/domains/">Domains</a>
<a href="/numbers/">Numbers</a>
<a href="/protocols/">Protocols</a>
<a href="/about/">About IANA</a>
<a href="/go/rfc2606">RFC 2606</a>
<a href="/about/">About</a>
<a href="/about/presentations/">Presentations</a>
<a href="/about/performance/">Performance</a>
<a href="/reports/">Reports</a>
<a href="/domains/">Domains</a>
<a href="/domains/root/">Root Zone</a>
<a href="/domains/int/">.INT</a>
<a href="/domains/arpa/">.ARPA</a>
<a href="/domains/idn-tables/">IDN Repository</a>
<a href="/protocols/">Protocols</a>
<a href="/numbers/">Number Resources</a>
<a href="/abuse/">Abuse Information</a>
<a href="http://www.icann.org/">Internet Corporation for Assigned Names and Numbers</a>
<a href="mailto:iana@iana.org?subject=General%20website%20feedback">iana@iana.org</a>
```